# How to save ICollection data to database with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have searched and tried dozen of solutions for my problem, but cant get this working.

I have compressed the class definitions here, but here are the main parts.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Device = new HashSet<Device>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
    }
    public int      Id { get; set; }
    public string   DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser  User { get; set; }
}
```

UserController.cs:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveDevice(string id, string selection)
{
    var selectedDevice = db.Devices.Where(u => u.DeviceId.Equals(selection));
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    user.Devices.Add(selectedDevice.First());

==> here everything looks ok, device data can be seen from the user data
==> in comments different things that I have tried so far, without getting anything to work
    //db.Entry(user).Property(p => p.Devices).IsModified = true;
    //db.Entry(user).Reference(p => p.Devices).IsLoaded = true;
    //db.Entry(user).Collection(p => p.Devices).IsLoaded = true;
    //db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Users.Attach(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

==> now, when I return to user details view, the device data is empty, so nothing has be stored to db

Comment: Did you try simplifying the code a bit. First try removing the relationship between User and Device. Then just try to save Device only and see if it works. Then add the code that attach the User.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What you mean by removing the relationship? If I removed the ICollection Devices from the ApplicationUser class, how can I add a device for it?

Comment: Are you trying to store different devices for one user?

Comment: Yes, the aim is that devices are already existing/stored to the db. Then then one is selected (maybe user can have multiple devices == ICollection??). With that deviceID (== given string/name) it is then searched from the db and it is saved to the user data. So then when accessing to user detailed view, the device data can be read/shown.

Comment: I assume your data is not get saved. Did you check the profiler to see what query get executed?

Comment: Hi Spock. I have now tried to learn about this mvc on my own about 3 months. I have get the basic view functionality working, but ran into trouble with this existing db data connecting to another data and Yes to your question, That device data isnt saved to user data. Basic user data and device data exists in the db and can be accessed/viewed. What you mean by "Profiler"??

Comment: Hi all... It seems that I finally solved this problem of mine.


UserController.cs:

public ActionResult SaveDevice(string id, string selection)
{
    var selectedDevice = db.Devices.Where(u => u.DeviceId.Equals(selection));
    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id);
    user.First().Devices.Add(selectedDevices.First());
    
    // This seems to de the trick
    UpdateModel(user,"Devices");
                    
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}